Two different optimal values for negated constraints
When I run this program in PuLP that is supposed to minimize the unconstrained gamma variable, I get infeasible.  Notice the constraint signs are mixed ≤ and ≥. The gamma variable in the dictionaries represents a weight placed on the importance of that goal.  But when I negate the constraints to make them all ≤, which should be the same thing, I get a solution.  What am I missing here about how PuLP works?
My question is based on the fact that the goal 1, 2, 4, and 5 constraint inequalities should be mathematically the identical but the program solutions are different.
For example, goal 1 is initially written as x3 + x6 +16/6 gamma ≥ 1.
Then I negate it to be  -x3 - x6 - 16/6 gamma ≤ -1  which is the same.  Why does Pulp give two different solution?
import pulp as lp

# Define the problem
prob = lp.LpProblem("Annual_usage", lp.LpMinimize)

# Decision variables
# x_i is the project type
x = {
    'X1': lp.LpVariable('x_1', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X2': lp.LpVariable('x_2', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X3': lp.LpVariable('x_3', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X4': lp.LpVariable('x_4', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X5': lp.LpVariable('x_5', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X6': lp.LpVariable('x_6', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X7': lp.LpVariable('x_7', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X8': lp.LpVariable('x_8', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'gamma': lp.LpVariable('gamma', lowBound=None, cat='Continuous')
}

# Usage
usage = {
    'X1': 4.7, 'X2': 12.5, 'X3': 3.2, 'X4': 7.5, 'X5': 41,  'X6': 47,   'X7': 23,  'X8': 16,
    'gamma': 0
}

# Costs
cost = {
    'X1': 75,  'X2': 180,  'X3': 350, 'X4': 45,  'X5': 120, 'X6': 80,   'X7': 115, 'X8': 210,
    'gamma': 0
}

# Acreage
acreage = {
    'X1': 7,   'X2': 12,   'X3': 20,  'X4': 6, 'X5': 3,   'X6': 25,   'X7': 5,   'X8': 8,
    'gamma': 0
}

goal1 = { # at least 1 of X3 and X6
    'X1': 0,   'X2': 0,   'X3': 1,  'X4': 0, 'X5': 0,   'X6':  1,   'X7': 0,   'X8': 0,
    'gamma': 16/6
}

goal2 = { # at least 130
    'X1': 4.7, 'X2': 12.5, 'X3': 3.2, 'X4': 7.5, 'X5': 41,  'X6': 47,   'X7': 23,  'X8': 16,
    'gamma': 16/3
}

goal3 = { #sum is at most 7
    'X1': 3,   'X2': 2,    'X3': 1,   'X4': 3, 'X5': 2,   'X6':  1,    'X7': 2,   'X8': 3,
    'gamma': 16/2
}

goal4 = { #at least 495)
    'X1': 75,  'X2': 180,  'X3': 350, 'X4': 45,  'X5': 120, 'X6': 80,   'X7': 115, 'X8': 210,
    'gamma': 16
}

goal5 = { # sum is at least 5
    'X1': 1,   'X2': 1,   'X3': 1,  'X4': 1, 'X5': 1,   'X6':  1,   'X7': 1,   'X8': 1,
    'gamma': 4
}

gamma_objective = { 
    'X1': 0,   'X2': 0,   'X3': 0,  'X4': 0, 'X5': 0,   'X6':  0,   'X7': 0,   'X8': 0,
    'gamma': 1
}


# Objective function
prob += lp.lpSum(gamma_objective[i] * x[i] for i in x)

# Constraints
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal1[i] for i in x) >= 1, "goal 1"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal2[i] for i in x) >= 130, "goal 2"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal3[i] for i in x) <= 7,  "goal 3"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal4[i] for i in x) >= 495, "goal 4"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal5[i] for i in x) >= 5, "goal 5"

prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * cost[i] for i in x) <=550, "# cost constraint"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * acreage[i] for i in x) <=50, "# acreage constraint"


# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# Print the solution
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

print("Total Cost =", lp.value(prob.objective))

status = prob.status
print("Status:", lp.LpStatus[status])

This is the code that gives me a solution when I negative the 1st, 2nd, 4th, and 5th goal constraints.
import pulp as lp

# Define the problem
prob = lp.LpProblem("Annual_usage", lp.LpMinimize)

# Decision variables
# x_i is the project type
x = {
    'X1': lp.LpVariable('x_1', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X2': lp.LpVariable('x_2', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X3': lp.LpVariable('x_3', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X4': lp.LpVariable('x_4', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X5': lp.LpVariable('x_5', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X6': lp.LpVariable('x_6', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X7': lp.LpVariable('x_7', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'X8': lp.LpVariable('x_8', lowBound=0, cat='Binary'),
    'gamma': lp.LpVariable('gamma', lowBound=None, cat='Continuous')
}

# Usage
usage = {
    'X1': 4.7, 'X2': 12.5, 'X3': 3.2, 'X4': 7.5, 'X5': 41,  'X6': 47,   'X7': 23,  'X8': 16,
    'gamma': 0
}

# Costs
cost = {
    'X1': 75,  'X2': 180,  'X3': 350, 'X4': 45,  'X5': 120, 'X6': 80,   'X7': 115, 'X8': 210,
    'gamma': 0
}

# Acreage
acreage = {
    'X1': 7,   'X2': 12,   'X3': 20,  'X4': 6, 'X5': 3,   'X6': 25,   'X7': 5,   'X8': 8,
    'gamma': 0
}

goal1 = { # at least X3 and X6
    'X1': 0,   'X2': 0,   'X3': -1,  'X4': 0, 'X5': 0,   'X6':  -1,   'X7': 0,   'X8': 0,
    'gamma': -16/6
}

goal2 = { # at least 130
    'X1': -4.7, 'X2': -12.5, 'X3': -3.2, 'X4': -7.5, 'X5': -41,  'X6': -47,   'X7': -23,  'X8': -16,
    'gamma': -16/3
}

goal3 = { #sum is at most 7
    'X1': -3,   'X2': -2,    'X3': -1,   'X4': -3, 'X5': -2,   'X6':  -1,    'X7': -2,   'X8':-3,
    'gamma': -16/2
}

goal4 = { # At  least 495k
    'X1': -75,  'X2': -180,  'X3': -350, 'X4': -45,  'X5': -120, 'X6': -80,   'X7': -115, 'X8': -210,
    'gamma': -16
}

goal5 = { # sum is at least 5
    'X1': -1,   'X2': -1,   'X3': -1,  'X4': -1, 'X5': -1,   'X6':  -1,   'X7': -1,   'X8': -1,
    'gamma': -4
}

gamma_objective = { 
    'X1': 0,   'X2': 0,   'X3': 0,  'X4': 0, 'X5': 0,   'X6':  0,   'X7': 0,   'X8': 0,
    'gamma': 1
}


# Objective function
prob += lp.lpSum(gamma_objective[i] * x[i] for i in x)

# Constraints
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal1[i] for i in x) <= -1, "goal 1"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal2[i] for i in x) <= -130, "goal 2"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal3[i] for i in x) <= 7,  "goal 3"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal4[i] for i in x) <= -495, "goal 4"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * goal5[i] for i in x) <= -5, "goal 5"

prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * cost[i] for i in x) <=550, "# cost constraint"
prob += lp.lpSum(x[i] * acreage[i] for i in x) <=50, "# acreage constraint"


# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# Print the solution
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

print("Total Cost =", lp.value(prob.objective))

status = prob.status
print("Status:", lp.LpStatus[status])


So, what is your question?  You've written a LP that is infeasible, and then you randomly flipped around some of the signs in the constraints and it is feasible and you want somebody to trace out the infeasibility for you?

I can see that it may come off that way, but no.  Initially, the constraints for goals 1, 2, 4, and 5 are given as ≥, and the program is infeasible.  But when I switch all the signs and therefore the direction of the inequality, it becomes feasible.   My question is why am I getting two different solutions when mathematically the constraints are the same?

check your negation of Goal 1.  You have 1-6/6 where I think you intend -16/6.  There may be other issues... I stopped looking there.  Print both problems and compare them line-for-line.  print(prob)

What does gamma actually represent?

So you've broken equivalence, but not addressed the root problem of infeasibility. Don't bother tinkering with different representations; use only the most obvious and easy-to-debug formulation from a business perspective. As is often the case, you've over-used dictionaries when you should be using matrices, sums and dot products. Goal 3 is too aggressive. You need to relax it (or your other constraints) to make the problem feasible:
import pulp


x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8 = project_types = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
    name='x', cat=pulp.LpBinary, indices=range(1, 9))
gamma = pulp.LpVariable(
    name='gamma', cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='Annual_usage', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)

usage = pulp.lpDot(project_types, (4.7, 12.5, 3.2, 7.5, 41, 47, 23, 16))
cost = pulp.lpDot(project_types, (75, 180, 350, 45, 120, 80, 115, 210))
acreage = pulp.lpDot(project_types, (7, 12, 20, 6, 3, 25, 5, 8))

prob.addConstraint(
    name='goal1',
    constraint=x3 + x6 + 16/6*gamma >= 1,
)
prob.addConstraint(
    name='goal2',
    constraint=usage + 16/3*gamma >= 130,
)
goal3 = pulp.lpDot(
    project_types,
    (3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3),
) + 16/2*gamma
prob.addConstraint(
    name='goal3',
    constraint=goal3 <= 13,  # 7
)
prob.addConstraint(
    name='goal4',
    constraint=cost + 16*gamma >= 495,
)
prob.addConstraint(
    name='goal5',
    constraint=pulp.lpSum(project_types) + 4*gamma >= 5,
)
prob.addConstraint(
    name='cost',
    constraint=cost <= 550,
)
prob.addConstraint(
    name='acreage',
    constraint=acreage <= 50,
)

prob.setObjective(gamma)
print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, '=', v.value())

print('usage =', usage.value())
print('cost =', cost.value())
print('acreage =', acreage.value())
print('goal3 only reduced to', goal3.value())

Annual_usage:
MINIMIZE
1*gamma + 0.0
SUBJECT TO
goal1: 2.66666666667 gamma + x_3 + x_6 >= 1

goal2: 5.33333333333 gamma + 4.7 x_1 + 12.5 x_2 + 3.2 x_3 + 7.5 x_4 + 41 x_5
 + 47 x_6 + 23 x_7 + 16 x_8 >= 130

goal3: 8 gamma + 3 x_1 + 2 x_2 + x_3 + 3 x_4 + 2 x_5 + x_6 + 2 x_7 + 3 x_8
 <= 13

goal4: 16 gamma + 75 x_1 + 180 x_2 + 350 x_3 + 45 x_4 + 120 x_5 + 80 x_6
 + 115 x_7 + 210 x_8 >= 495

goal5: 4 gamma + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 >= 5

cost: 75 x_1 + 180 x_2 + 350 x_3 + 45 x_4 + 120 x_5 + 80 x_6 + 115 x_7
 + 210 x_8 <= 550

acreage: 7 x_1 + 12 x_2 + 20 x_3 + 6 x_4 + 3 x_5 + 25 x_6 + 5 x_7 + 8 x_8
 <= 50

VARIABLES
gamma free Continuous
0 <= x_1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_5 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_6 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_7 <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_8 <= 1 Integer

...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                0.56250000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               4
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

gamma = 0.5625
x_1 = 0.0
x_2 = 0.0
x_3 = 0.0
x_4 = 0.0
x_5 = 1.0
x_6 = 1.0
x_7 = 1.0
x_8 = 1.0
usage = 127.0
cost = 525.0
acreage = 41.0
goal3 only reduced to 12.5

